# Is there a C++/CLI equivalent to a C# cast to a dynamic type?

Tags: c#, dynamic, c++-cli, visitor-pattern, double-dispatch

I'm extending a class hierarchy written in C# that implements a Visitor pattern (double-dispatch) using the dynamic keyword, as described [here](https://dariosantarelli.wordpress.com/2012/12/08/c-dynamic-dispatch-and-class-inheritance/#comment-2945).

Here is some very simplified pseudo-code of what I'm currently doing in C#:

```
public class Command { 
   ...
}

public class RunCommand : Command {
   ...
}


public class Base {
   ...
   // Double-dispatch interface 
   public virtual void AcceptCommand(Command command) {
      HandleCommand((dynamic)command);
   }

   // Example of a specialization that handles a RunCommand 
   protected virtual void HandleCommand(RunCommand command) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Now, when I extend the hierarchy, derived classes may require handling new `Command` specializations not known to the base class. **In this case, the double-dispatch will fail** (it seems as if dynamic overload resolution won't traverse the extended class hierarchy while trying to match a method). **There is an easy fix for this (described in the previously linked article) and it consists in overriding the `AcceptCommand()` method on the derived class (duplicating the original implementation)**, like this:

```
public class Derived : Base {
   // Override to allow double-dispatch to handle commands introduced by Derived
   public override void AcceptCommand(Command command) {
      HandleCommand((dynamic)command);
   }
}
```

Now, recently I required extending the hierarchy with classes from a project implemented in C++/CLI for convenience (a lot of interaction with unmanaged WIN32 API code). This project introduced several `Command` specializations, so I need to override The `AcceptCommand()` method in the C++/CLI class as I do in C# in order to fix double-dispatch, but the problem is **I don't know how to perform the cast of the `Command` object to a dynamic type in C++/CLI syntax. Is this something possible?**

Comment: something like dynamic_cast? See http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/

Comment: Dynamic typing is not supported in C++/CLI. You'd have to write a DLR call site by hand.

Comment: @Peter `dynamic_cast` is the equivalent of C#'s `as` keyword. It's unrelated to the `dynamic` keyword.